# Using CSS to force img and p to split into two columns

Tags: html, css, image, paragraph

I have a dynamically generated content which generates one `img` and a few accompanying `p`s. I'd like to force the img to take up one column and have the rest of the `p`s in another. I did this by floating the `img` and adding padding at the bottom to clear and force the text into the second column.

This works fine but it breaks at smaller screen sizes. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Effectively I want to apply `clear: below` to the `img`… but of course that is not possible.

Here's a fidde: http://jsfiddle.net/EFw6w/

CSS:

```
.two-col {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    }

    .two-col p {

        }

    .two-col p img {
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 5%;
        float: left;
        padding-bottom: 30%;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="two-col">
    <p><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" /></p>
    <p>Duis laoreet sagittis ipsum, volutpat interdum dui gravida ac. Integer mattis facilisis eleifend. Sed ullamcorper leo sit amet enim egestas sagittis. Fusce gravida accumsan placerat. Ut in ultrices mi, ut posuere sem. Vivamus bibendum mollis lectus vitae scelerisque. Ut faucibus tortor leo, nec ullamcorper erat cursus nec.</p>
    <p><a href="#">Kittens</a></p>
</div>
```

Any thoughts appreciated…

Comment: I'm assuming you can't just have the two paragraph elements with the text and link in a separate div?

Comment: I am not understanding why you cannot clear?

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/EFw6w/8/

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry I misunderstood the question at first.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Thanks but that's not a responsive solution. It breaks when the text becomes longer than the img. I need to clear below the img so nothing can appear beneath it.

Comment: Slightly better: http://jsfiddle.net/EFw6w/17/

Comment: What's wrong with the answer I provided? It's entirely responsive.

Comment: @AlexPodworny, I'm using Wordpress to generate the content and the img and text and generated in the same div.

Answer (score 0):

You could enclose all your `<p>` elements into a div, and your `<img>` into another div. Then set the width (45%) to the div's:

http://jsfiddle.net/2b6k2/4/

```
<div class="two-col">
    <div id="first-col" class="column">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
    </div>
    <div id="second-col" class="column">
        <p>Duis laoreet sagittis ipsum, volutpat interdum dui gravida ac. Integer mattis facilisis eleifend. Sed ullamcorper leo sit amet enim egestas sagittis. Fusce gravida accumsan placerat. Ut in ultrices mi, ut posuere sem. Vivamus bibendum mollis lectus vitae scelerisque. Ut faucibus tortor leo, nec ullamcorper erat cursus nec.</p>
        <p><a href="#">Kittens</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: That's good but I can't add extra markup around the text. I'm using Wordpress and the image and text are all generated inside a div wrapped in <p> tags. @lpg

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example at js fiddle,

[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/EFw6w/14/)

I am sorry I misunderstood the question. Correct me if I am wrong but you are trying to stop the text from wrapping at different window sizes?

The `P` is a block element so you just need to float it so it stays next to the `img` then give it a width so it knows not to `wrap`.

Here is what I changed on your css.

```
  .two-col p {
     width:50%;
     float: left;
        }

    .two-col img {
        width: 45%;
        float: left;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have dynamically generated elements you could use this CSS-

```
.two-col {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.two-col p {
    display: inline;
}

.two-col p:after{
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}

.two-col :first-child {
    float: left;
}
```

Making the `p`s `inline` will give you a responsive layout. And `content: "\A"` will add a new line to the end of each paragraph. You can use `content: "\A\A"` if you want more space between paragraphs.

Comment: Hmmm thanks but I don't see how this forces no content to fall beneath the `img` element? @aniskhan001

Comment: The `img` is now floated. Because all the paragraphs are now displayed as `inline` it's maintaining the desired format.

Comment: Oh, really sorry. That was my fault. A space was needed between `.two-col` and `:first-child`. Previously I wrote `.two-col:first-child` by mistake. It should be `.two-col :first-child`. I have also fixed the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it the result you wanted? The image is in the left and texts in the right.

Comment: Shrink the page making it narrower. The text is floating underneath the image. That's exactly what the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: Well, for small devices I think texts should go beneath the image as it make more sense for responsive layout. But if you don't want that, then you can use JS to retrieve the `width` of div containing image then set that value (or greater) as `margin-left` to rest of the divs.